# Dynamic CRM 2011 SDK 5.0.13 ExecuteMultipleRequest sample code formatter threw exception

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am testing the ExecuteMultipleRequest which is a interesting new feature my Dynamic CRM Online Environment. But I bumbed into errors:

I encounter during Runtime 
[image: Runtime error]

I encounter during Debug

[image: Debug error]

I know the latest roll up has been pulled. Is this why ExecuteMultipleRequest is not working? I find other blogs that seems to make it work [Dynamics CRM Execute Multiple – Performance Tests](http://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/roshan/roshan-mehtas-blog/2013/01/09/dynamics-crm-execute-multiple-performance-tests)  , Probably before it was pulled?

Comment: Are you sure that the latest roll-up is effective? Also, are you sure you're using on-line version? (I've seen once a dude who said it was on-line CRM because he's using "internet window" and the URL was *localhost:5555* or something like that.)

Comment: Definitely using CRM Online.

Comment: Just checking. I've done some un-brilliant things myself, haha. That's strange, though. As far I can tell, mine on-line accounts were updated automagically. I don't get the icons on the lower side of the NAV and the spinner is blue, not green (might have to do with me working on IE10). Do you see those changes too?

Comment: That's cool. The IE10 difference is interesting. My users are using IE9 & lower, I just tried signing up for a CRM Online trial and it’s still using the pre Polaris version 5.0.9690.2747. Now I am thinking the Polaris upgrade is only supported for Dynamics CRM Online with 365, unless somebody disproves that. :)

Comment: The new version is currently being rolled out so you might or might not have it. But you surely will have it soon. Although, I got some indications from a source I can't reveal, that there were huge issues with RU12 and that the on-premise installation file has been removed from the download center.

Comment: The on premise rollup was pulled out. [link](https://community.dynamics.com/product/crm/crmnontechnical/b/crmconnection/archive/2013/01/15/update-on-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-update-rollup-12-release.aspx) Meanwhile the CRM Online is scheduled, that's why I don't have it yet.

Answer (score 2):

Your environment needs to have UR12. If you are on CRM Online your administrator should have been notified if your environment has been updated, but in any case you can check by going to File > Help > About in the CRM web client. If you are on UR12 then your build version should be 5.0.9690.3218

Comment: I am an Adminstrator for a CRM Online Instance and I checked, we are still using the pre polaris version 5.0.9690.2747. I heard from a colleague the roll up was pulled. Can somebody confirm this?      I do have a "theory" it's looking like the Polaris upgrade is a GO for Dynamic CRM Online with 365. I can't confirm that right now since there are new country restriction for Dynamic CRM Online with 365, they incorporated a text notification verification!

Comment: We are using CRM Online (with O365) and we have several environments that are using UR12 (and several more that I have been notified will be updated within the next week). I've heard nothing of the update being pulled (again).